# Getting updated node information after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, calendar, ajax

I am trying to get a list of html elements using jQuery on a Calendar view page. However, since calendar can change months, weeks, etc. asynchronously, how do I get the up-to-date information using some code on the page like below:

```
$(".class-name")
```

EDIT: Adding more detail to what I am trying to do.

One of the departments in my company is listing out the daily news articles in calendar format. The news articles are uploaded to a document library in PDF format with the article date. Now when the item shows up on the Calendar, the link takes you to the item view rather than the attachment (news article) directly. My approach to opening the attachment directly from the calendar view:

1. Get all the URLs on the calendar view.
2. Get the IDs for each item.
3. Get the URL of the file for each ID. (I have the code for this part done).
4. Replace the item URL on the calendar view with the file URL.

The part that I need help with is #1. I am having trouble getting the all the item URLs given the fact that the calendar view can be changed during runtime to show different days/weeks/months.

Comment: Hi Tom, I think you need to add more details about what you are trying to do. This will help you attract more attention to you issue!

Comment: Hi Robert, Just added some more details and context to the question. Thanks!